# Access User's Browser (preferably Chrome) cache in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on something where I provide content to users based on the things they view over the internet, or by the kind of applications they use. Is there a way to get a user's search history, bookmarks or cache from various browsers (preferably Chrome). Also is there a way to get the 'search parameters' typed by the user to install apps on Play Store. The aim is to create a background service that helps understand user search habits on the mobile platform.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't because every android application in a sand box for more information go to this link:[Sand Box](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)

and if you want to do sort if thing you must implement  rooted application and the database file in chrome is encrypted

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.